# property dependency symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dependencies

Suppose I have two bundles: a FormBundle and an AccommodationBundle. These bundles I would like to Open Source independently from each other.

FormBundle i.e. has a class FormEvent

```
class FormEvent {
    /**
      * @ORM\ManyToMany(
      *   targetEntity="Visit",
      *   mappedBy="formEvents",
      *   cascade={"persist","remove"})
      **/
     protected $visits;
}
```

Now as you may understand, the Visit-entity is part of the AccommodationBundle.

How do I make the property **visits** part of the FormEvent class, only if the AccommodationBundle is registered? Do I need to extend the class FormEvent in the AccommodationBundle?

Comment: Basically you can't.  It least not without trying to dig into modifying the doctrine 2 metadata.  Instead you might want to have an event listener in the accommodation bundle which would return visits for a given form event.